# Finding unknowns by least squares method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem in estimating parameters using a least squares method using the relation Ax = b. I have the values of `x` and `b` and `A` is a 9 by 9 matrix containing the unknowns as given below

```
A = np.array([[R,S,0,0,0,T,0,0,0],
              [Q,R,S,0,0,0,T,0,0],
              [0,Q,R,S,0,0,0,T,0],
              [0,0,Q,R,S,0,0,0,T],
              [0,0,0,Q,R,S,0,0,0],
              [P,0,0,0,Q,R,S,0,0],
              [0,P,0,0,0,Q,R,S,0],
              [0,0,P,0,0,0,Q,R,S],
              [0,0,0,P,0,0,0,Q,R]])

x = np.array([[11], [20], [13], [43], [5], [63], [72],[84], [96]])

b = np.array([[10], [2], [4], [3], [5], [1], [7],[6], [9]])
```

where `P = (W + X)`

```
Q = (W + 2*Y)

R = (2*W - 0.1)

S = (W - X)
T = (W - 2*Y)
```

I need to get the values of `W`, `X` and `Y`.
Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you attempt the problem?

Comment: Yes@alec_a. I used the code:  x_est = linalg.solve(A.T.dot(A), A.T.dot(b)) I got the following error message "No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc solve". What do I need to add into my code? Thanks